# Plotting the most frequent words in a text (removing stop words)

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I'm trying to plot the most frequent words in a DataFrame that has the following columns `tags` and `text`.

This DataFrame is a mix of `True` and `Fake` news. True news has a value of `0` in the DataFrame and Fake news has a value of `1`:

```
                      tags              text

kt-rOnMBAC-oqacdW1Q-    1   On Monday night, Donald Trump traveled to West...
k9-rOnMBAC-oqacdW1Q-    1   Donald Trump is very busy right now trying to ...
lN-rOnMBAC-oqacdW1Q-    1   By now, we all know that upon having emergency...
ld-rOnMBAC-oqacdW1Q-    1   Donald Trump s horrible decisions and disgusti...
lt-rOnMBAC-oqacdW1Q-    1   It s tough sometimes to imagine that Donald Tr...
... ... ...
Y-CvOnMBAC-oqacdBwEJ    0   BRUSSELS (Reuters) - NATO allies on Tuesday we...
ZOCvOnMBAC-oqacdBwEJ    0   LONDON (Reuters) - LexisNexis, a provider of l...
ZeCvOnMBAC-oqacdBwEJ    0   MINSK (Reuters) - In the shadow of disused Sov...
ZuCvOnMBAC-oqacdBwEJ    0   MOSCOW (Reuters) - Vatican Secretary of State ...
Z-CvOnMBAC-oqacdBwEJ    0   JAKARTA (Reuters) - Indonesia will buy 11 Sukh...
```

I already plot the data using the following code:

```
import nltk
from nltk import tokenize

tokenSpace = tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer()
def counter(text, columnText, quantity):
    allWords = ' '.join([text for text in text[columnText].astype('str')])
    tokenPhrase = tokenSpace.tokenize(allWords)
    frequency = nltk.FreqDist(tokenPhrase) 
    dfFrequency = pd.DataFrame({"Word": list(frequency.keys()), "Frequency": list(frequency.values())}) 
    
    dfFrequency = dfFrequency.nlargest(columns = "Frequency", n = quantity)
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    ax = sns.barplot(data = dfFrequency, x = "Word", y = "Frequency", palette="deep")
    ax.set(ylabel = "Count")
    plt.xticks(rotation='horizontal')
    plt.show()
```

When i call the function:

```
counter(df2[df2['tags'] == 1], 'text', 20)
```

I get the following Plot:

[image: most frequent words for fake news]

So now my question is:

Is there a way to get as a result only the significant words? (Like skip low-meaning words. Such as (this, the, to...))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do that. You normally define your stop words:

```
my_stop_words = ['the','and','to','of','was','with','on','in','for','no','name',
                 'is','he','or','at','as','one','she','am','you','his',
                 'your','were','by','pt','not','her','be','this','are','there',
               'had','date','from','first','an','that','have','but','has','please','which',
                'namepattern','seen','every','fax', 'home', 'telephone', 'given', 'after', 
                'also','will', 'un', 'up', 'well', 'time', 'any']
```

And then filter them out:

```
# remove stopwords
vect = CountVectorizer(max_features = 3000, tokenizer = note_flatner, stop_words = my_stop_words)
```

In your case you can do it by:

```
dfFrequency = dfFrequency [~dfFrequency ['Word'].str.contains('|'.join(my_stop_words))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter those low meaning words (stopwords) manually.
The NLTK library has a list of stopwords if you don't want to define your own:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords = list(stopwords.words('english'))
```

NLTK is downloadable by pip

```
pip install nltk
```

Then install the stopwords using

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
```